# jQuery access Ajax Response from PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a PHP function where I pass a variable to and it returns an array containing a start date and end date.

```
<?php
 function dateRangeTimeFrame($var1){
  ...

  $date['startDate'] = $startDate;
  $date['endDate'] = $endDate;

  return $date;
 }
?>
```

I am also trying to use this PHP function in an AJAX call so I can reuse the code. I have added this to the beginning of the page:

```
if (isset($_POST['dateFunction'])) {
  print_r(dateRangeTimeFrame($_POST['dateFunction']));
}
```

My jQuery code is as follows:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/functions.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { "dateFunction": theDate},
    success: function(response) { 
        console.log(response['startDate']); 
        console.log(response.startDate); 
    }
});
```

My issue is that I do not know how to access the response that the php function is returning.

Here is the response I am getting from the PHP function:

```
Array
(
  [startDate] => 2015/01/17
  [endDate] => 2015/02/16
)
```

How would I go about getting these 2 vars from the PHP response?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use JSON. Your Javascript natively understands and can parse it

```
if (isset($_POST['dateFunction'])) {
   echo json_encode(dateRangeTimeFrame($_POST['dateFunction']));
}
```

And your jQuery (note I added `dataType`)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/functions.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'post',
    data: { "dateFunction": theDate},
    success: function(response) { 
        console.log(response.startDate); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    <?php
     function dateRangeTimeFrame($var1){
      ...

      $date['startDate'] = $startDate;
      $date['endDate'] = $endDate;

      return json_encode($date);
     }

?>
```

jQuery

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'includes/functions.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: { "dateFunction": theDate},
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) { 
       console.log(response.startDate); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
function dateRangeTimeFrame($var1) {
   // ...

   $date['startDate'] = $startDate;
   $date['endDate'] = $endDate;

   echo json_encode($date);
}
?>
```

### Ajax

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'includes/functions.php',
   type: 'post',
   data: { "dateFunction": theDate },
   success: function(response) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
         alert(response[i].startDate);
      } 
   }
});
```